# How can I store comments for a post using Parse & Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm honestly stumped as to how I could do this. I've been searching and trying out different methods for the past day or so and none have worked. What I'm basically trying to do is store comments for a post (Each row represents a post). I've been reading through the Parse documentation and have tried to implement some of the things that they have there into my code in order to achieve this, but that hasn't worked out either. If anybody could help me out, I'd be extremely greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact task is the example provided in the documentation.

http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-data

You need to create a new class called "Comments" and then refrence its parent post as one of it's columns.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed this example in the documentation. Thank you so much for linking that and I'm sorry that I had to waste your time due to my own rushed reading of the document. I'll be sure to take it easier and slow down the next time I'm reading the documentation for any api/service.